# Building a static library for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have built a static library for iOS. My problem is that I use ASIHTTPRequest as an example in my library, and when I add my library to an app that already uses the ASIHTTPRequest library, I get compiler errors, until I remove all ASIHTTPRequest .m files from the project that uses my library.

Is there a way around this ? Like for example build the static library and make it require the ASIHTTP libraries instead of them being added to the project ?

EDIT :

Here is an example of the error I get once I "archive" the project.

```
ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/tj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/db-afhqjyfitjcnbqdmywezdvmryvyp/ArchiveIntermediates/db/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/db.build/Release-iphoneos/db.build/Objects-normal/armv6/fmdb.o and /Users/tj/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/db-afhqjyfitjcnbqdmywezdvmryvyp/ArchiveIntermediates/db/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/db.build/Release-iphoneos/db.build/Objects-normal/armv6/main.o for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Trausti

Comment: What are the compiler errors, most errors people get with this are to do with you duplicating the Reachability files.

Comment: I don't remember, but it was to do with all the .m files being already included

Comment: I can't check right now as I am doing a major rewrite of the library right now

Comment: Do you have a Reachability.m already in your project?  Guarantee that is it! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest is to make ASIHTTPRequest into a static library of its own, by adding it as a dependency project in your static library's project. Essentially what you do, is to create an xcode project, pack ASIHTTPRequest into it, close that project, then drag&drop the ASIHTTPRequest project file into your static library project's file navigator. This will add it as a dependency project and automatically build it as a static library and link your project against it.

When using your static library in one of your application projects do the same. It is easier to manage your static library as a dependency project which in turn has ASIHTTPRequest as another level of dependency. This way both of your projects will be able to see its headers, and link against it and there will be no duplicate symbol issues.

If you are trying to publish your static library to other developers then it is a more difficult situation...